# Ruby merge hashes with nil values

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I'm trying to merge the values from 2 hashes, creating a new one. I've tried with

```
Hash[b.map{|k,v| [a[k],v]}
```

but when it finds out that an "a" value is empty(nil) it doesn't print b[k]...I've got something like that:

```
|  A |  A  |        |  B |  B  | ====> |  C    |   C   |
| key|value|        | key|value| ====> |B_value|A_value|
| key|value|        | key|value| ====> |B_value|A_value|
| key| nil |        | key|value| ====>      MISSING
| key|value|        | key|value| ====> |B_value|A_value|
```

The keys are the same
I need to see also the nil.

If I try to print in array format I can see everything (nil included):

```
p = a.map{|k,v| [b[k],v]}
```

Probably map is not the right solution, there's something else that can give me the same result?

This is my code:

```
header_hostname = Hash.new
working_host = Hash.new
fileset.each do |file|
header = YAML.load_file("output/#{file}")
header.each do |k_header,v_header|
    if v_header == "Hostname"
        header_hostname = header
    end
end
working_host = Hash[header.map{|k, v| [header_hostname[k], v] }]
puts working_host
File.open("tmp/working_hosts.txt","a+") << working_host
```

the output from Hash is like:

...

```
Erogazione VlanID: '2390'
" SubnetorIP": 10.*.*.*
" Netmask": 255.255.255.240
" Gateway": 10.*.*.*
```

...

```
Backup VlanID: ''
Managment VlanID: ''
Privata HB VlanID: ''
Remote Console VlanID: ''
```

...

Hashes

```
Header = {"98"=>"Erogazione VlanID", "99"=>" SubnetorIP", "100"=>" Netmask", "101"=>" Gateway", "102"=>" Speed(f,g)", "103"=>" Bond(s/n)", "104"=>" Porte", "105"=>" Switch", "106"=>" Slot/Porte", "107"=>" PortePPanel", "108"=>" PortePPanel(bond)", "109"=>"Backup VlanID", "110"=>" SubnetorIP", "111"=>" Netmask", "112"=>" Gateway", "113"=>" Speed(f,g)", "114"=>" Porte", "115"=>" Switch", "116"=>" Slot/Porte", "117"=>" PortePPanel", "135"=>"Remote Console VlanID", "136"=>" SubnetorIP", "137"=>" Netmask", "138"=>" Gateway", "139"=>" Speed(f,g)", "140"=>" Porte", "141"=>" Switch", "142"=>" Slot/Porte", "143"=>" PortePPanel"}

Machine1 = {"98"=>"3315", "99"=>"10.*.*.*", "100"=>"255.255.255.240", "101"=>"10.*.*.*", "102"=>"g", "103"=>"", "104"=>"2.0", "105"=>"", "106"=>"", "107"=>"", "108"=>"", "109"=>"111", "110"=>"10.*.*.*", "111"=>"255.255.255.240", "112"=>"10.*.*.*", "113"=>"g", "114"=>"1.0", "115"=>"", "116"=>"", "117"=>"", "135"=>"111", "136"=>"10.*.*.*", "137"=>"255.255.255.240", "138"=>"10.*.*.*", "139"=>"", "140"=>"", "141"=>"", "142"=>"", "143"=>"" }
```

This is the output:

```
output = {"Erogazione VlanID"=>"3315", " SubnetorIP"=>"10.*.*.*", " Netmask"=>"255.255.255.240", " Gateway"=>"10.*.*.*", " Speed(f,g)"=>"", " Bond(s/n)"=>"", " Porte"=>"", " Switch"=>"", " Slot/Porte"=>"", " PortePPanel"=>"", " PortePPanel(bond)"=>"", "Backup VlanID"=>"111", "Remote Console VlanID"=>"111"}
```

Comment: show the actual output ands how are you printing ?

Comment: Do you know about the [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method?

Comment: The merge method merge old_value with new_value. I don't need this. I need to put B_value as key for the A_value.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to work fine, and will not produce a "missing" entry in the resulting Hash.

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: nil, d: 4 }
b = { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7,   d: 8 }

c = Hash[a.map{|k,v| [b[k],v]}]
# {5=>1, 6=>2, 7=>nil, 8=>4}
```

No issues for the `a[:c]` value, which is `nil`. It will generate the `7 => nil` mapping, as `b[:c]` is `7`.

Comment: You're right, it works fine. But with the hashes that I've posted it loses something..I'm pretty sure that it's my fault but I cannot see what is wrong with my code

Comment: Many values in the second Hash (`Machine1`) are duplicated, for example `"10.*.*.*"` and `""`. Since you use those as *keys* in the result Hash, and a Hash has unique keys, only the last mapping will be stored in the hash. I get different output than you anyway, are you even using `a = Header`, `b = Machine1` and run `Hash[a.map{|k,v| [b[k],v]}]` ? Because you would get a Hash starting like this: `{"3315"=>"Erogazione VlanID", "10.*.*.*"=>" Gateway", "255.255.255.240"=>" Netmask"`

Comment: I've omitted the IP's, they're different. Anyway my fault, it is a=Machine1 and b=Header (better: a = Header, b = Machine1 and Hash[b.map{|k,v| [a[k],v]}])